# Java implementation of MergeSort; cannot find the bug

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, debugging, mergesort

Ok, this is one of those desperate questions. I'm trying to implement Bottom-Up MS to sort and integer array. But goodness sake, I can't seem to find the bug...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A2 {

    public static boolean less(Integer v, Integer w) {
        return v.compareTo(w) < 0;
    }

    public static void sort(int[] a) {
        int N = a.length;
        int[] aux = new int[N];
        for (int sz = 1; sz < N; sz = sz + sz)
            for (int lo = 0; lo < N - sz; lo += sz + sz)
                merge(a, aux, lo, lo + sz - 1, Math.min(lo + sz + sz - 1, N - 1));
    }

    public static void merge(int[] a, int aux[], int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        int i = lo;
        int j = mid + 1;

        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
            aux[k] = a[k];

        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) 
            if (i > mid)
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            else if (j > hi)
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            else if (less(aux[j], aux[i]))
                a[k] = a[j++];
            else
                a[k] = a[i++];

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int next = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        int[] v = new int[size];
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
        String[] sa = s.split("[\\s]+");
        while (next < size) {
            v[next] = Integer.parseInt(sa[next]);
            next ++;
        }
        for (Integer i : v)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        sort(v);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            System.out.print(v[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

In the `main` function, I print the elements of the array, just to be sure that the problem is in the sorting. The first number is just the size of the array. The bug is either in the `sort()` or in the `merge()`.
Here's some sample outputs:

```
9
10 45 20 5 -6 80 99 -4 0
10 45 20 5 -6 80 99 -4 0 
----------------------------------
-6 -4 -4 -6 -4 -4 -6 0 99 

6
6 7 3 2 4 1
6 7 3 2 4 1 
----------------------------------
1 1 1 4 6 7 

5
6 5 2 3 4
6 5 2 3 4 
----------------------------------
2 3 4 5 6
```

This last one seems just fine.

Please help me, I've been going around and around and I cannot seem to find the bug.

Comment: Try to print some message in the `merge` method, find out when the problem start occur.. Use smaller input (4 2 1 3) which has problem to debug. And try using [debugger] (https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php) to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `merge()` method: in the last 2 cases in the loop, you copy values from `a` instead of from `aux`. It is not a problem when you copy `a[j++]` but when you copy `a[i++]` the value may have been overwritten already.

Considering that the values in the right slice are only written after they have already been copied, you only need to save the left slice.

Here is a modified version with this simplification:

```java
    public static void merge(int[] a, int aux[], int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        int i = lo;
        int j = mid + 1;

        for (int k = lo; k <= mid; k++)  // save a[lo..mid] to aux
            aux[k] = a[k];

        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
            if (i > mid)
                a[k] = a[j++];
            else if (j > hi)
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            else if (less(a[j], aux[i]))
                a[k] = a[j++];
            else
                a[k] = aux[i++];
        }
    }
```

Note that it would be less error prone to consider `mid` to be the start of the right slice and `hi` to be the index one past the end of the slice. The `sort()` loop would be simpler, without tricky +/-1 adjustments. Incidentally the inner loop test in your version is off by one, albeit without consequences aside from inefficiency. It should be:

```
for (int lo = 0; lo < N - sz - 1; lo += sz + sz)
```

Here is a further simplified implementation with included/excluded slices and an combined test:

```java
    public static void sort(int[] a) {
        int N = a.length;
        int[] aux = new int[N];
        for (int sz = 1; sz < N; sz = sz + sz)
            for (int lo = 0; lo < N - sz; lo += sz + sz)
                merge(a, aux, lo, lo + sz, Math.min(lo + sz + sz, N));
    }

    public static void merge(int[] a, int aux[], int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        for (int i = lo; i < mid; i++) { // save a[lo..mid[ to aux
            aux[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (int i = lo, j = mid, k = lo; i < mid; k++) {
            if (j < hi && less(a[j], aux[i]))
                a[k] = a[j++];
            else
                a[k] = aux[i++];
        }
    }
```

This version is very simple but still not very efficient on large arrays because each pass goes through the whole array, defeating the processor cacheing scheme. It would be more efficient to perform bottom up merging incrementally, using a stack of sorted subarrays of increasing sizes.

Comment: For N not a power of 2, I don't see where the last N-sz elements are sorted without the fix noted in my answer.

Comment: @rcgldr: I'm afraid I don't see why your fix is needed: in the inner loop, if `lo` is >= `N - sz`, the subarray `a[lo..N[` is already sorted because its size is <= `sz`, which was sorted in the previous pass. With your version, `merge` is called with `mid == hi`, which causes 2 copies of the left subarray with no changes.

Comment: I wasn't taking into account that the OP merge sort code always copies data to the temp array, then merges back. So as you commented, if there is a single subarray a[lo..N] left at the end of a merge pass, it doesn't need to be handled. In the case of an optimized merge sort that changes direction with each pass (or level of recursion), a[lo...N] or aux[lo...N] would need to be copied to the other array. The 3rd section of my answer shows this case.

Comment: @rcgldr: How much of an improvement do you get from this optimisation? On large arrays, I would expect at least 30% from merging incrementally (depth-first) instead of the OP's breadth-first approach.

Comment: To avoid unneeded copies, top down can change direction of merge based on level of recursion, bottom up on each pass. I tested with n = 2^24 = 16777216 pseudo random 64 bit unsigned integers. Top down is about 2% slower than bottom up. Note that top down pushes and pops about 2·n pairs of indexes, so you can think of top down time complexity as O(n·(1+log2(n)) and bottom up as O(n·log2(n)). For n = 2^24, that's O(25·n), versus O(24·n), about 4% difference, but since the stack is in L1 cache, the overhead is less. Most libraries for stable sort use hybrid bottom up merge sort + insertion sort.

Comment: Regarding depth first versus breadth first, a typical X86 (and other modern processors) has 8 way associative caches, and a lot of cache lines. A standard 2-way merge will use 2 cache lines for the 2 runs to be merged, and 1 cache line for the merged output, so breadth first is not an issue.  Looking at std::stable_sort() C++ template for Visual Studio, it's dated back to 1994, and it is a hybrid bottom up merge sort + insertion sort. The templates used by VS are/were maintained by Dinkumware.

Answer (score 0):

With this change, it works on my system.

```
            else if(less(aux[j], aux[i]))
                a[k] = aux[j++];             // fix  (aux)
            else
                a[k] = aux[i++];             // fix  (aux)
```

If the merge sort was avoiding a copy step by changing the direction of merge with each pass, if there is a single run left over at the end of a merge pass, it needs to be copied. The 3rd section in this answer has an example of this.

---

The usage of less(...) intermittently doubles the run time on my system when I tested using larger arrays (like 8 million ints) with random values. Changing if(less(aux[j], aux[i])) to if(aux[j] < aux[i]) seems to have fixed this or made it very rare.

---

Example code for a somewhat more efficient merge sort, which avoids doing copies unless there is an odd number of passes. This could be avoided by calculating number of passes first, and if the number of passes is odd, swap in place. This could be extended to larger sub-groups by using insertion sort on groups of 32 or 64 elements on the initial pass.

```
    public static void sort(int[] a) {
        int n = a.length;
        if(n < 2)
            return;
        int[] dst = new int[n];
        int[] src = a;
        int[] tmp;
        for(int sz = 1; sz < n; sz = sz+sz){
            int lo;
            int md;
            int hi = 0;
            while(hi < n){
                lo = hi;
                md = lo+sz;
                if(md >= n){            // if single run remaining, copy it
                    System.arraycopy(src, lo, dst, lo, n-lo);
                    break;
                }
                hi = md+sz;
                if(hi > n)
                    hi = n;
                merge(src, dst, lo, md, hi);
            }
            tmp = src;                  // swap references
            src = dst;                  //  to change direction of merge
            dst = tmp;
        }
        if(src != a)                    // copy back to a if needed
            System.arraycopy(src, 0, a, 0, n);
    }

    public static void merge(int[] src, int[] dst, int lo, int md, int hi) {
        int i = lo;
        int j = md;
        int k = lo;
        while(true){
            if(src[j]< src[i]){
                dst[k++] = src[j++];
                if(j < hi)
                    continue;
                System.arraycopy(src, i, dst, k, md-i);
                return;
            } else {
                dst[k++] = src[i++];
                if(i < md)
                    continue;
                System.arraycopy(src, j, dst, k, hi-j);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `less` is not used *intermittently*, it is used systematically for all element comparisons, which is inefficient but is probably an attempt at making the algorithm generic with a replaceable sorting order.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes - The issue is the running time for 8 million integers is about 1.2 seconds some of the time, 2.4 seconds some of the time. If I remove `less`, the running time remains consistent at about 1.2. seconds.

Comment: this might be a side effect of the JIT compiler. Given the specificity of the `sort()` and `merge()` methods that operate on `int` arrays, it does not make much sense to use a comparison method that is not replaceable, so getting rid of it is indeed advisable.

Answer (score -1):

you can try with this code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort
{
   public static void merge(double[] a, 
                            int iLeft, int iMiddle, int iRight, 
                            double[] tmp)
   {
      int i, j, k;

      i = iLeft;
      j = iMiddle;
      k = iLeft;

      while ( i < iMiddle || j < iRight )
      {
         if ( i < iMiddle && j < iRight )
         {  // Both array have elements
            if ( a[i] < a[j] )
               tmp[k++] = a[i++];
            else
               tmp[k++] = a[j++];
         }
         else if ( i == iMiddle )
            tmp[k++] = a[j++];     // a is empty
         else if ( j == iRight )
            tmp[k++] = a[i++];     // b is empty
      }

      /* =================================
         Copy tmp[] back to a[]
         ================================= */
      for ( i = iLeft; i < iRight; i++ )
         a[i] = tmp[i];
   }

   public static void sort(double[] a, double[] tmp)
   {
      int width;

      for ( width = 1; width < a.length; width = 2*width )
      {
         // Combine sections of array a of width "width"
         int i;

         for ( i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 2*width )
         {
            int left, middle, right;

        left = i;
        middle = i + width;
        right  = i + 2*width;

            merge( a, left, middle, right, tmp );

         }

         System.out.println("After 1 iter: " + Arrays.toString(a) );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't, I need to follow that API... I really need to find my bug.